# Regex for multiple occurrences of specific words

Tags: java, regex, validation, salesforce, apex

Hello

I'm trying to create a validation rule that checks the regular expression to accept only specific phrases. Regex is based on Java.

Here are examples of correct inputs:

`1OR2`

`2`

`1 OR 2 OR 15`

`(  2OR3) AND 1`

`(12AND13 AND1)OR(4   AND5)`

`((2AND3 AND 1)OR(4AND5))AND6`

but I would be happy if only the regex could accept anything like :

`())34AND(4`

I have no idea how to create a regex to check if the brackets open and close correctly(they can be nested). I assumed it can be impossible to check it in regex so the proper validation for the brackets I've already made in the code(stack implementation). In the code I have a second step validation of the phrase.

All I need the regex to do is to check if there are these specific things inside the phrase:

numbers, round brackets, words AND and OR with multiple occurrences and whitespaces are allowed.
It should NOT accept letters or other characters.
All I managed to create so far is this:

`^[0-9 \\(][0-9 \\(\\)]*`

also tried adding something like:

`\\b(AND|OR)\\b`

inside the second pair of brackets but with no luck.

I cannot figure out how to correct it to add OR and AND words.

Comment: If the brackets can be nested then regex is definitely the wrong tool for the job. Regular expressions are incapable of handling recursion. It sounds like you want to write a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following and matched all the inputs you gave:

```
^[^\)][0-9 \( (AND|OR)]*$
```

I assumed you didn't want to start with ), which is why I included ^[^\)].

In case you weren't aware, I use https://www.regexpal.com to check my regular expressions for code.

Comment: Thank you for your example, this really helped

Comment: @Mikke this pattern does not properly validate the phrases in question. See: https://regex101.com/r/qF2H3X/1

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an arbitrary number of nested elements it's arguably not possible with regex.

For demonstration purposes only, this matches zero or more conjunctions and one set of parenthesis:

```
^\d+(\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*(\d+|\(?\s*\d+(\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*\d+)\s*\)))*$|^(\d+|\(?\s*\d+(\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*\d+)\s*\))\s*(\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*\d+)*$
```

That's it. Adding more sets and levels of nested parenthesis leads to exponentially increasing complexity - till it breaks altogether.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Ufc0C/1)

Comment: thanks for this complex example, it shows that it will be impossible to check brackets

Comment: @Mikke yes, unfortunately. If the answer was helpful to you please consider to upvote/accept.